# How can I define a specific range for storing values in database?

Tags: mysql, size

I want to know, how can I define a limited range (max and min) for storing values in table?

I want this **range:** `[min: -99 , max: 999]`

Also here is some example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   code INT(11) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO MyTable (id,code)
             VALUES (1, 42),
             VALUES (2, -332),
             VALUES (3, -83),
             VALUES (4, 44324),
             VALUES (5, 0),
             VALUES (6, 999);
```

So, I want this output:

```
// MyTable
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
| 1  | 42   |
| 2  | -99  |
| 3  | -83  |
| 4  | 999  |
| 5  | 0    |
| 6  | 999  |
+----+------+
```

Well, How can I restrict my table for just accepting valid (in range) values or before storing, converts them to max/min value?

---

Or, If what I considered in above is not possible, Then how can I show the result as valid in range?

```
// MyTable
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
| 1  | 42   |
| 2  | -332 |
| 3  | -83  |
| 4  | 44324|
| 5  | 0    |
| 6  | 999  |
+----+------+
```

I want something like this query:

```
SELECT id, IF(LENGTH(code) > 999, '999', code)) AS FilteredCode FROM MyTable
// also I can not implement to filter negative values (-99) in my query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CHECK constraint like this:

```
CONSTRAINT code_fk CHECK (code  BETWEEN -99 AND 999)
```

So your table will be created as:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   code INT(11) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT code_fk CHECK (code  BETWEEN -99 AND 999)
)
```

See the **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3381)**

Comment: Seems good. Just one thing, What happens if the value does not be in range? It won't insert?

Comment: @Shafizadeh:- It will throw an error. I have updated my answer  with the Fiddle link demonstrating that!

Answer (score 1):

Using **check constraint** to do this below like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
code INT(11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT code_fk CHECK (code  BETWEEN -99 AND 999)
)
```